# Not able to give newline in email content in protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor

In my protractor script,I have a string, which i am using for sending email  as given below.

```
var resNoLocString="51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459aaaa,90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541aaaa,01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659aaaa";
resNoLocString=resNoLocString.replace(/aaaa,?/g,"\n");
resNoLocString=resNoLoc.length+" were failed, and they are: "+"\n"+resNoLocString;
console.log(resNoLocString);
const msg1 = {
 to: ['xxxxx@gmail.com'],
 from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
 subject: 'Test Result', 
 text: resNoLocString, 
}; 
sgMail.send(msg1);
```

but it is not displaying in new lines in the email received as given below

```
3 were failed, and they are:51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459 90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541 01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659
```

But when i am print it in the command prompt,it is displaying in new lines.And if i am using below code

```
var resNoLocString=resNoLoc.toString()
resNoLocString=resNoLocString.replace(/aaaa,?/g,"\n"+"\n");
resNoLocString=resNoLoc.length+"were failed, and they are: "+"\n"+"\n"+resNoLocString;
console.log(resNoLocString);
```

then it will displaying in new lines.but 2 newlines are appearing in both email received and in command prompt as given below.

```
3 were failed, and they are:

51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459

90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541 

01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659
```

So how can i align the string with only one newline in the email content.My aim is to receive the email content in below format

```
3 were failed, and they are:
51 Cart Road #408, Missouri City, TX 77459 
90 South Street, Southern Pines, NC 87-541 
01 Cart Road #7708, Missouri City, TX 7659
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodemailer and provide mail options as below:

```
let mailOptions = {
            from: 'XXX',
            to: 'XXX',
            subject: 'XXX',
            text: 'XXX',
            html: 'resNoLoc.length+" were failed, and they are:<br>+resNoLocString;',

          };
```

Comment: Thanks i got it..i have replaced all  "\n", with "<br>" and given    html: resNoLocString,    in email(msg1 ) .So that the email received with required new lines.